# How to recover folder converted to file by check disk?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, check-disk

After turning on my computer, check disk checked my flash drive and converted corrupted folder to a file.
How can I recover data from converted folder?

Below is the message I found in bootex.log file on my hard drive after conversion happened.

> Checking file system on E:   The type
>   of the file system is FAT.
>
> One of your disks needs to be checked
>   for consistency. You   may cancel the
>   disk check, but it is strongly
>   recommended   that you continue.
>   Windows will now check the disk. 
>   Volume Serial Number is 0A34-16CA
>   Unrecoverable error in folder
>   \Documents\divers.   Convert folder to
>   file (Y/N)? Yes   Convert lost chains
>   to files (Y/N)? Yes   705036288 bytes
>   in 43 recovered files.   Windows has
>   made corrections to the file system.

Answer (score 5):

chkdisk sometimes converts your folder to file type during the scan. To recover your data, follow the below steps.

1. Go to *Change folder and search* option ->  *View*  -> check *Show hidden files* and uncheck *Hide protected operating system files*.
2. You should see a folder with name "found.***" in your drive. Right-click on that folder and take ownership or grant yourself read/write permission on this folder through the *Security* tab.
3. Now open "found.***" folder. There might be multiple "dir***.chk" folders inside.
4. Go through each folder. One of them should have your lost data. You can simply copy/paste from here.

Comment: Yup worked for me very well.. Thanks a bunch for saving time...

Comment: People say there are angles on the earth but I did not believe it. Now I`m sure you are one of them. You saved my life man!!!

Answer (score 2):

Normally this data isn't easily recoverable. Try a combination of tools to see if indeed you can recover anything.

[CHK-Mate](http://www.diydatarecovery.nl/chkmate.htm), plus the [UnCHK and FileCHK](http://www.ericphelps.com/uncheck/) combo.
Good Luck!

Comment: I'd like to know the results, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is unknow to me but the fact is that folder are not actually converted into file. The exe files of each folder name are created and folder are set hidden.

I recovered my folders by setting their attributes unhidden.

Follow these steps:

Click start--->Run

Type CMD----> press enter

Change driver by typing drive letter following ":" symbol
now set folder attributes as below example:

attrib My Document -s -h

here you can replace "My Document" folder name with yours...

Answer (score 0):

### Complementary answer: in case those hidden files and folders cannot be accessed and/or copied.

**In Linux such files are easily accessible and the correct extension is visible.**
A [Linux-live usb](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2-requirements) is the way to go. I recommend Xubuntu or Linux Mint Xfce for this purpose.

On a Linux-Windows dual boot laptop I had a problem with a big folder (located on a third, non-system ntfs partition) which has been named in a way that was acceptable on Linux, but which Windows check-disk found erroneous, something like `BIG_FOLDER************`. Windows check-disk had scanned that drive before without losing any files but at one time it made this folder go away. It was in fact hidden inside the `found.004` folder which couldn't be even copied. Trying the [EaseUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OegzZ.png) trial (limited) tool in Windows I was able to see that all my BIG_FOLDER files were there all right, but couldn't be recovered with the free version of that program.

In Linux I have accessed them very easily with a normal file manager.

[image]

[image]

Note that in my case I had multiple such `found.xxx` folders, but that none of them could be accessed (permission denied). All of them except the one I was interested in could be copied though (on an external drive, and there they were accessible). The one I needed couldn't even be copied in Windows. In Linux they behaved like normal files and folders.